# How to move (not just drag) a div ?HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have dynamic divs which I can drag and drop into two different parent divs but I want to also be able to move them. Here is the Javascript code:

```
      function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {           
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop_to_customer(ev) {
        const el = document.querySelector("[id=" + "\'" + ev.dataTransfer.getData("text") + "\'" + "]");

        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'submit.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                data: "1"
            }
        });
    }


    function remove_from_customer(ev) {
        const el = document.querySelector("[id=" + "\'" + ev.dataTransfer.getData("text") + "\'" + "]");
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'submit.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                data:"1"
            }                
        });
    }
```

What should I add in order to make that work? I need to move them just like in this example but remember the id of the divs changes because they are dynamic. http://jsfiddle.net/wfbY8/4/

EDIT:
https://jsfiddle.net/burimsyla/9c6bm0xk/9/

Comment: Assuming the elements are already `position: absolute` or `fixed`, which they would need to be in order to drag them, then you can just amend their `top` and `left` values in CSS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am sorry but why did you change my post? Thats not my code, that's something I found on Fiddle.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and I cant have position:absolute because they would be placed on top of each other

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I thought you'd put an actual useful working example in the fiddle, instead of just referring to it. Please add a working example of your code. To make elements draggable they **have** to be absolutely positioned.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I prepared a Fiddle just to see how the current drag is working, you are not gonna be able to drop but never mind that part, I just need to move divs instead of dragging so you can focus in this one. See Edited post!